# Continuously update app extension

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-extension

I have created an app extension for the notification center which actually works fine except for I am not able to update its `UILabel` continuously. The reason I need to do this is because my app has a constantly changing data set which I want to show in the extension.

I have tried using `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`for updating the data in the extension but it's not working. Here is my code:

#### Registering for change notification (Extension)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:)
                                                 name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.company.app"];
    //update label
}
```

#### Sending data to extension

```
- (void)updateData
{
    NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.company.app"];
    [sharedDefaults setInteger:seconds forKey:@"seconds"];
    ...
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
}
```

I have App Groups correctly set up in both the main app and the extension who are both accessing the same group.

Does anybody know why this is not working or if there is another method to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So are you suggesting that your `userDefaultsDidChange` function isn't firing?

Comment: yes. the `viewDidLoad` method will get called so it should be registering the notification but it is never called.

Comment: I believe there are some issues with `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` with a shared defaults database in an extension. As in - it doesn't work and you can't do a thing about it. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I have the same issue.  My handler for NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification is NOT called.

But, using a repeating timer and re-reading does work...  I don't like polling...

Comment: @freshking: Have u got the solution for this?

Comment: @JasmeetSingh No, I refrained from needing this. But check nonchote's answer below. It sounds promising.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue in my WatchKit app and `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` does indeed **not** get triggered in the extension for the shared `NSUserDefaults`.

The best solution I've found is a library called [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) which uses 
`CFNotificationCenter Darwin Notifications` to achieve this.

Comment: Just stumbled over this question having the same problem as OP. this looks so cool! I will give this a go later on :)